# Is it possible to cancel Breeze requests (AngularJS)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, breeze

I'm trying to find a way to cancel BreezeJS queries for the purpose of implementing a live search that queries BreezeJS on keypress (see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23436699/546561)).

I know that in Angular, `$http` requests can be cancelled by passing a promise to the `timeout` parameter in the `config` object, and then calling `resolve()` on that promise.

I also know that I can get BreezeJS to use my module's `$http` insance with:

```
var ajax = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular');
ajax.setHttp($http);
```

So I was thinking about possibly creating a `request` interceptor on `$http` that would set `config.timeout` to a promise.  But that still leaves me quite a few steps away from solving the problem, because I would somehow need to be able to give the promise to my interceptor from the code running the query (so that the querying code could `resolve()` the promise if needed).

Is there a better way?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update 16 May 2014

You can set HTTP-level timeout and cancellation with the AJAX Adapter's `requestInterceptor` as of v.1.4.12. See the documentation, ["Controlling AJAX calls"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/controlling-ajax).

## Original answer

The **EntityManager** HTTP service operations don't offer cancel or timeout options. Maybe they will someday.

The v.1.4.11 Breeze **AJAX adapters** don't offer cancel or timeout options either. *But they will in v.1.4.12* and you can see the preview on github right now.

The samples on github illustrate both cancel and timeout with the new adapters. For users of the jQuery AJAX component there is [***DocCode**:jQueryAjaxAdapterTests.js*](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/jQueryAjaxAdapterTests.js). For users of Angular's `$http` there is the [***Zza-Node-Mongo**:ajax-adapter.async.spec.js*](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/node/zza-node-mongo/client/test/specs.async/ajax-adapter.async.spec.js).

It's best if you can run the samples but if you can't (perhaps because you don't use one of the technologies involved), the test files (see links above) are easy to read and you should glean the ideas that will help. At least I hope so.

### Usage

Cancel and timeout are useful features. Do you need them for your use case? Maybe. But you'd want to take a first step of de-bouncing the text that users enter into your "live search" so that you aren't firing off 100s of pointless queries.

That observation is discussed in [your related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436699/preserving-asynchronous-query-order-in-breeze-angular).

Comment: The cancel feature is live in v.1.4.12 now

Comment: this is a bit off topic, but I was wondering if you'd be willing to look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23795982/546561 and let me know if it's a sane approach?